# Understanding data.table syntax

Tags: r, data.table

I'm following in the footsteps of a past co-worker and am needing to manipulate some data he was structuring. Therefore, I'm reading through and duplicating his code so I understand what he did.

However, I've come to a section that I know what he was trying to accomplish but I don't understand his indexing.

I typically do similar work with loops and so this is a coding approach I'm not familiar with.

Here's the line(s):

```
IDs         <- unique(cummingsOUT$ID)
c2          <- cummingsOUT[, .(Weeks20 = sum(WEEK<21)),by=ID][Weeks20 >= 18]
cummingsOUT <- cummingsOUT[cummingsOUT$ID %in% c2$ID ,]
```

So "cummingsOUT" is a rather large longitudinal data set of 3 million some obs. of 6 variables of 431,000 individuals. The 6 variables are ID(numerical), GRADE(factor), SCORE(numerical), WEEK(numerical), MEASURE(factor), DATA(factor). For each individual, it is possible to have multiple SCORE's in the same WEEK.

At this point, the co-worker was instructed to retain only unique ID's which had 18 or more SCORE's by their personal WEEK 20.

The first line I get, although he doesn't end up using IDS. It's the second one that stumps me.

```
 c2          <- cummingsOUT[, .(Weeks20 = sum(WEEK<21)),by=ID][Weeks20 >= 18]
```

What is going on here? He creates an object, c2, and sets it equal to the data set for all rows. But what does the "." do? And can someone interpret Weeks20? Is he creating a new object, WITHIN the index, that is summing the total observations for an individual, up to data points that are matched to the value of 20 in WEEK? And then he indexes again?

The third line I believe is him just matching ID's that were identified as having 18 or more obs by Week 20.

Anyone think they can explain what's going on?

Comment: Please read [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started). This is a very basic `data.table` syntax.

Comment: Never used data.table  before. Thanks for the simple link, it really helped.

Answer (score 3):

First, read the docs, as @DavidArenburg suggested.

Then walk through step by step. We can ignore your first line - It isnt used here.

I'll use the mtcars dataset as you did not provide reproducible data

```
#load data.table
library(data.table)
#copy mtcars, as otherwise it's locked
mtcars <- copy(mtcars)
#turn it into a data.table
setDT(mtcars)
#make the new variable
new <- mtcars[,.(numofgoodcars = sum(mpg > 20)), by = cyl]
```

We now have new, which should look like this:

```
   cyl numofgoodcars
1:   6             3
2:   4            11
3:   8             0
```

It is a summary, with a new column, `numofgoodcars`, for each `cyl`, exactly as was done for your `Weeks20`, by `ID`.

Then, the original coder subsetted the data, by those with Weeks20 > 18 - let's do the same for `new`:

```
new[numofgoodcars > 4]

   cyl numofgoodcars
1:   4            11
```

The original coder simply put these two steps together:

```
mtcars[,.(numofgoodcars = sum(mpg > 20)), by = cyl][numofgoodcars > 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
c2          <- cummingsOUT[, .(Weeks20 = sum(WEEK<21)),by=ID][Weeks20 >= 18]
```

break this down:

```
cummingsOUT[, .(Weeks20 = sum(WEEK<21)),by=ID]
```

For the table cummingsOut, calculate a new table, one row for each ID, which contains the field Weeks20, calculated as the number of weeks for which WEEK is less than 21.

```
[Weeks20 >= 18]
```

Return only those rows for which Weeks20 is greater than 18.

So assuming the original data contains one score per week, you have:

Return one row for each user ID who has 18 or more scores in the first 20 weeks.

The by operator will preserve a copy of ID in each row, so now you just need to extract the ID fields to get the required result.